# Postgres uses Parallel Seq Scan over Index Scan for simple query

Tags: postgresql

Debugging a slow select query I found out with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` that Postgres uses Parallel Seq Scan for a very simple `SELECT` query on a large table (>80m rows).

#### Some background

I migrated a table within the same database with an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` query, which was working but took several hours. I than ran the following two queries on both tables which perform significantly different. Note, both tables have the exact same number of rows (a bit over 80 Mio rows) and have a Primary Key on columnd `id`.

#### On src table

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM tmp_migration.asset a 
WHERE id = 1452299
```

Yielding...

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"Gather  (cost=1000.00..2723419.51 rows=40149 width=2536) (actual time=56362.052..56411.077 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 2"
"  Workers Launched: 2"
"  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on asset a  (cost=0.00..2718404.61 rows=16729 width=2536) (actual time=53152.645..56349.660 rows=0 loops=3)"
"        Filter: (id = 1452299)"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 26851637"
"Planning Time: 0.077 ms"
"Execution Time: 56411.114 ms"
```

**Note**: almost a minute on a simple select

#### On target table

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM public.asset a 
WHERE id = 107588
```

Yielding...

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"Index Scan using ""PK_1209d107fe21482beaea51b745e"" on asset a  (cost=0.57..8.59 rows=1 width=883) (actual time=85.544..85.548 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: (id = 107588)"
"Planning Time: 0.090 ms"
"Execution Time: 85.576 ms"
```

**Note**: less then 100 ms execution time

#### What I tried so far

Checking PKs for both tables. Doing `VACUUM tmp_migration.asset`.

What causes this inefficient behavior?

### Update (Fix with help of comments)

Indeed, the index was missing. I ran

`SELECT * FROM pg_indexes WHERE schemaname = 'public' OR schemaname = 'tmp_migration'`

which was not giving any indexes in `tmp_migration`. Once I ran

```
CREATE INDEX "asset_idx" ON tmp_migration.asset ("id")
```

the query executed as expected. **The reason I was so sure** a PK already exists was my db GUI (Heidi SQL) reported a **PK** on that column. Should have double checked .

Thanks!

Comment: Have you run `ANALYZE tmp_migration.asset`?

Comment: Yes, it shows no output (should it?). Afterwards, query takes the same amount of time.

Comment: You don't describe having created any indexes on the new table.  And the evidence suggest you have not done so.

Comment: I agree with jjanes: you probably forgot to create the unique index (or primary key). The optimizer expects 16729  rows from the condition `id = 1452299` - a clear sign that there is no unique index on the column id (because then the optimizer would "estimate" 1 row as the result). The estimate also shows, that statistics haven't been collected for the table, does running `analyze tmp_migration.asset;` change anything?

Comment: @agoldev 1 year later and I had the exact same isue as you, query by ID not using an index scan, same issue with myself that the index wasn't on pg_indexes! Thanks for updating your question with the answer, saved my bacon.